# nltk Bayes classifier retrain

Tags: python, nltk

I try to train nltk Bayes classifier. Its possible to retrain classifier later(add more training data and train only on it) or I have to train the classifier in one try?

Comment: What does this question has to do with Python?

Comment: nltk is a python library and i`m looking for a python solution

Comment: With the NLTK implementation of the Naive Bayes Classifier, online / incremental learning is not possible. You can only train it again with the whole data set.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrain classifier on adding more data as and when it comes(called "online" naive bayes classifier). I am not sure if any standard python ML libraries does this. But I have found one which does it - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Divmod%20Reverend

try;

```
pip install Reverend
```